# How did my question get answered with zero views?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

How did [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/wasnt-there-going-to-be-a-different-ending-to-total-recall-originally) get answered with zero views (see screenshot)?

[image]

Comment: @jeff - why did you add **by design**? surely the effect is just a bug - you didn't design that!

Comment: caching is by design. Just wait and see the viewcount. If it's still wrong in an hour then let us know. (This varies by traffic -- if the site is getting 1 hit per hour it may take a while.)

Comment: @Jeff - thanks. If I see it again I'll be in touch. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same effect on another question on one of the other stack exchange sites.   I've noticed that there can be a delay on the reporting of various data, but usually the question data is reported pretty fast.  [In this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/0-view-but-2-answers-the-main-page-works-in-a-strange-way), Robert Cartaino♦, mentions it's caching that causes this effect.